# The antonym of freethinker

Tags: single-word-requests

Atheist Dan Barker said:

> **Freethinkers** reject faith as a valid tool of knowledge.

Taking it as it is, what would be the opposite of freethinker in the above context? **Restricted-thinker**, **constrained-thinker**, something else?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

> rigid thinkers

as a direct antonym, or

> dogmatists

if you want to emphasise that they are adhering to a particular predefined set of beliefs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the opposite of a *freethinker* is a [**conformist**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conformist):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *noun*
>   : one who conforms : a person who behaves in accordance with prevailing standards or customs and typically dislikes or avoids unconventional behavior
>   // I'm running with the herd and swimming with the tide and being a good little *conformist*.
>   — Florence King
>
> *adjective*
>   : following or seeking to enforce prevailing standards or customs : opposing or avoiding unconventional thinking and behavior
>   // The original Beats rebelled against a postwar society they saw as staid, *conformist* and commercial.
>   — Jeff Giles and Michael Rubiner

---

Although *freethinker* itself does not have a specifically religious context, if you want its opposite in that context, then consider [**adherent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adherent):

> : one who adheres to something: such as
>   **a** : a follower of a leader, party, or profession
>   // Freud's *adherents*
>   **b** : a believer in or advocate especially of a particular idea or church
>   // *adherents* of Christianity
>   // *adherents* of socialism

Answer (score 0):

At [synonyms.com](https://www.synonyms.com/synonym/freethinker) we find

> **freethinker**
>   Synonyms:
>   agnostic, atheist, deist, disbeliever, doubter, infidel, skeptic, unbeliever
>   Antonyms:
>   believer, Christian